# Proving convergence in probability (WLLN)

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent r.v.'s on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Decide if the following sequences satisfy a weak law of large numbers, i.e that

$\frac{1}{n}[S_n - \mathbb{E}(S_n)] \overset{p}{\to} 0$,

Where $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$, and prove the statements.

1. $\mathbb{P}(X_n = \sqrt{n}) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = -\sqrt{n}) = \frac{1}{2n}, \; \mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) = \frac{n-1}{n}$,
2. $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 2^n) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = -2^n) = \frac{1}{2}$

Edit:

I have tried to calculate the expected value, and it seems that, from what I can see, that  for the first, $E(S_n)$ looks (graphically) similar to the logarithm of n, and so $E(S_n)/n$ converges to 0. $\sum_{i} \frac{1}{2i}$ does not converge though. So by Borel Cantelli $P(\limsup_j E_j) \neq 0$. But this is where I'm uncertain, and I'm not sure what to do with $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) = \frac{n-1}{n}$. Intuitively it feels like 1. should hold, and 2. should not, but I'm not sure if thats correct, and I haven't figured out how to show it rigoruously.

Comment: What have _you_ done towards solving your homework problem by yourself?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I have updated the OP.

Comment: Hello. Please add the [tag:self-study] tag.

Comment: Since $E[X_n]=0$ for all $n$, why does $E[S_n] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i]= \sum_{i=1}^n 0$ seem to behave like $\log n$?

Comment: I was confused and tried to plot it in wolfram alpha, but I can see that I was on the wrong tarck. I have since made progress on the problem, and managed to calculate the expectation and variance of $S_n$ to show that $E(S_n) = 0$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{Var(S_n)}{n^2} = 0$ so the WLLN holds. I think for the 2nd case $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{Var(S_n)}{n^2} = \infty$ hence it does not satistfy WLLN. Is this correct? I think my calculations are sound now.

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly a self-study problem. These are typical exercises. So, here I am leaving a possible mode of attack that OP can employ to handle such genre of problems.

What are the things required for the weak law of large numbers to hold true?

**Definition $1.$** (cf. $[\rm I],$ chapter $7,$ p. $303$) *Let $\langle X_n\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of random variables. Let $S_n := \sum_{k=1}^n X_k, ~~n\in \mathbb N. $ Then $\langle X_n\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ obeys the weak law of large numbers with respect to the sequence $\langle B_n\rangle_{n\in \mathbb N},~B_n>0,~B_n\uparrow \infty, $ if there exists a sequence of real constants $A_n$ such that $\frac{(S_n-A_n)}{B_n}\overset{\mathbb P}{\to} 0$ as $n\to\infty.$*

It's an easy exercise to show the definition holds for $\langle X_n\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ (the one that OP is acquainted with) for $A_n =\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb E[X_n]$ and $B_n = n$ provided
\begin{align}\mathbb E[X_i]&< \infty,~~ \forall ~i\tag 1\\ \mathfrak V_n := \operatorname{Var}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right]&<\infty,\tag 2\\\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mathfrak V_n}{n^2} &= 0;\tag 3\end{align}

$(3) $ is sufficient (but not necessary).

Now, let $\langle X_n\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be independent.

A road-map to follow to assess whether WLLN holds true:

$\bullet$ Check $(1), ~(2), ~(3). $

$\bullet$ If all of them are true, then WLLN is applicable to the sequence of rvs.

What happens if $(3) $ fails?

**Theorem $1.$** (Markov) (cf. $\rm [II],$ chapter $\rm X, $ pp. $191-195$) *The weak law of large numbers holds if for some $\delta > 0,$ all the mathematical expectations $\mathbb E\left(|X_i|^{1+\delta}\right);~ i = 1,2,\ldots$ exist and are bounded.*

$\bullet$ If $(3) $ fails, check whether Theorem $1.$ holds for suitable choice(s) of $\delta \in \mathbb R^{>0}.$

$\bullet$ If for each $i,~\mathbb E\left(|X_i|^{1+\delta}\right)$ exists and is bounded, i.e. if the conditions of Theorem $1.$ hold, then WLLN is applicable. Otherwise, not.

---

### References:

$\rm [I]$ An Introduction to Probability and Statistics, *Vijay K. Rohatgi, A. K. Md. Ehsanes Saleh,* John Wiley & Sons, $2015.$

$\rm [II]$ Introduction to Mathematical Probability, *J. V. Uspensky,* McGraw-Hill Book Company, $1937.$

Comment: Thanks. I am confident that I have solved the problem now.

Comment: Very good @Manbearpig. Answers to such questions should be more generic so that future readers might gain more info than in the more restricted sense the OP might be asking.